# Benefits/Drawbacks of Auth Options (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, authentication

What are the benefits/drawbacks of these Auth options, as displayed on my Firebase Auth menu?

[image]

Here is some context about my app:

1. My app isn't security critical, hence:
2. I want to optimize for a quick / easy Auth experience
3. My app is only Mobile
4. I expect my users to stay logged in unless they manually sign out or are using a new / different phone.

And of course development and maintenance costs should be considered.

Answer (score 1):

> **TL;DR** Use the "additional providers" and focus on building your app rather than building authentication systems.

Firebase Authentication is a powerful and reasonably easy to use tool that gives you(r app) the ability to authenticate your users using **their** preferred auth mechanism (rather than your proprietary system requiring your users to remember passwords for myriad sites).

If your users already have a Google, Microsoft, Facebook, Apple etc. account, enabling the relevant subset from these "additional providers" adds very little overhead to your code but increases the chances your users will already have an account that they can use.

In addition, because e.g. Google, Microsoft, Facebook, Apple is handling authentication for you, your app becomes simpler and, unless you choose the native providers (phone, email) (which you should probably not do) you don't have to take on the burden in being diligent in managing your users' credential (e.g. email, passwords etc).